# Laptop display not working - but external monitor is (Antergos)

Tags: display, antergos

When I boot, everything shows up on my laptop screen until the desktop environment starts to load, after that I am left with the

```
starting version 235
AntergosRoot: clean, 623842/30138368 files, 17962021/120534016 blocks
```

text on my laptop screen, but everything works fine on my external monitor. If I press Ctrl-Alt-F2 I can get a shell on my laptop screen, but my external monitor goes black and I cannot get it back without rebooting.
I suspect it is something to do with the graphics card, since that was what I was trying to do when it broke. (I think it was the `nvidia-installer` antergos package that broke it.) If I boot with the external monitor disconnected, the laptop display still doesn't work. Here is my system configuration:

```
OS: Antergos Linux x86_64
Host: Latitude E6430 01
Kernal: 4.14.3-1-ARCH
Resolution: 1280x1024
DE: KDE
WM: KWin
CPU: Intel i7-3740QM (8) @ 3.700GHz
GPU: Intel Integrated Graphics
GPU: NVIDIA NVS 5200M
Memory: 5842MiB
```

`lspci` gives the following output:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v2/3rd Gen Core processor PCI Express Root Port (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI Host Controller (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family KT Controller (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville) (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev c4)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev c4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev c4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev c4)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C210 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev c4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation QM77 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 7 Series/C216 Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108GLM [NVS 5200M] (rev a1)
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Centrino Advanced-N 6205 [Taylor Peak] (rev 34)
0c:00.0 SD Host controller: O2 Micro, Inc. OZ600FJ0/OZ900FJ0/OZ600FJS SD/MMC Card Reader Controller (rev 05)
```

What I was originally trying to do when it broke was navigate the minefield of hybrid graphics, eventually deciding to remove `nvidia`, `nouveau` and `bumblebee` in favour of the `nvidia-installer` package, along with `antergos-prime`.

Answer (score 0):

Delete all of the nvidia drivers, reinstall, then delete xorg.conf.d.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Welcome on the site! I suggest to give more detailed answers, explain the reason and so on.